# Connection reset by peer error while using celery stats()

Tags: python-2.7, flask, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to get stats for my celery Que (rabbitmq). I'm using celery.app.control.Inspect().stats() API. I'm doing this on a web server, I can get the stats only one time. If I refresh the page I'm getting "**[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**" Error. how can I deal with this.

/**init**.py

```
celtasks = Celery(app.name,"rabbit mq url")
```

/helpers.py

```
get_stats():
     stats = celtasks.control.Inspect().stats()
     return stats
```

whenever there is a request "get_stats" function is hit. It is only working for the first request after this, it says connection reset by peer error.

If I go by connection has been reset and try to create the connection again, I get error

updated /helpers.py

```
 get_stats():
     celtasks = Celery(app.name,"rabbit mq url")
     stats = celtasks.control.Inspect().stats()
     return stats
```

Rabbitmq logs

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::14:11:54 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.29185.6> (10.246.170.70:48618 -> 10.24.83.115:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=WARNING REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::14:11:54 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.29197.6> (10.246.170.70:48620 -> 10.24.83.115:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
"rabbit@oser000300.log-20170625" 9054L, 361662C
```

Answer (score 1):

AT most times , CONNECTION RESET BY PEER is because the server close the connection itself, however the client does not know . When client want to communicate to sever through this broke connection, it receive this ERROR. In your case , maybe the hang time (time interval between two stats()) is too long, and server think this connection is useless and close it .

Comment: get_stats():                                                                                                             
      celtasks = Celery(app.name,"rabbit mq url")
     stats = celtasks.control.Inspect().stats()
     return stats                                                                                      
 what do you think it the right solution? I'm not allowed to open the connection twice.If I do that I'm getting an error.

Comment: other api request is ok? and is it getstats() called often ? did you check the broker's state? Or maybe you should think use connection pool ?

Comment: All the Api requests have the same problem. i have the broker logs 
=WARNING REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::14:11:54 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.29185.6> (10.246.170.70:48618 -> 10.24.83.115:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=WARNING REPORT==== 10-Jul-2017::14:11:54 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.29197.6> (10.246.170.70:48620 -> 10.24.83.115:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
"rabbit@oser000300.log-20170625" 9054L, 361662C

Comment: maybe this is because client didn't close the connection properly . you can search "rabbitmq connection_closed_abruptly" to find more infomation.